# runhaskell error attempting to use module `main:Prelude' (.\Prelude.hs) which is not loaded

Tags: haskell, runhaskell

I am attempting to run a simple Haskell program using `runhaskell file.hs`. The source code looks like this:

```
main = putStrLn "hello world"
```

The output of `runhaskell` is an error, which I do not know how to fix:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
attempting to use module `main:Prelude' (.\Prelude.hs) which is not loaded
```

Comment: It is configuration problem. I just tried it and it works.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce this problem. Could you post your version and any relevant config information?

Comment: OK, most probably I will just reinstall the Haskell Platform.

Comment: @AndreiBozantan feel free to answer your own question if this works.